# List of hybrid app tools

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I'm doing some research for a paper and i need to find out how many tools that exists to make hybrid apps

I know some of the more popular ones.

- PhoneGap
- Appcelerators Titanium
- AppBuilder
- IBM Worklight

I know that i'm far from having an complete list of tools. So i turn to the collective help of this community. So if anyone can help make this list complete I would be forever grateful Thanks

... and it could help future hybrid developers pick their favourite tool

Comment: These types of questions are considered offtopic here on SO because they can't be answered definitively. Should you wish to create such a list then there is only one place: the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/hybrid-mobile-app/info).

Comment: Thats okay. Thanks. Just close the topic, delete or as you see fit :)

Answer (score 4):

**Multiple phone web-based application framework** 
[check this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web-based_application_framework)